# why my pandas groupby ffill will(may?) fill between different groupbys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, ffill

```
df = df.query('Time >= @start_time and Time < @end_time')
df.loc[:, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['ret'] = (df.groupby(['date', 'sym'])['Close']
               .ffill()
               .pct_change())
```

when I used this to calculate the return, I found that the first row of each `groupbyer's ['ret']` is not `NaN`. It shows a huge number which wouldn't be the return of a minute bar. So I guess `pandas ffill` between different groups. But I don't know how to solve this.

For example,
My DataFrame's columns are date, sym, Time, and Close.

The result is supposed to be

|  | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 30986938 | NaN |
| 30986939 | 0.000934 |
| 30986940 | 0.001386 |
| 30986941 | -0.000461 |
| 30986942 | 0.000462 |
| 30986943 | -0.000180 |
| 30986944 | 0.000180 |

but it gives

|  | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 30986938 | -0.148827 |
| 30986939 | 0.000934 |
| 30986940 | 0.001386 |
| 30986941 | -0.000461 |
| 30986942 | 0.000462 |
| 30986943 | -0.000180 |
| 30986944 | 0.000180 |

I tried use `apply`/`transform(lambda x: x.ffill())` or `groupby(, as_index=False)`. All don't work.

I found the bug. I should use

```
df.groupby(['date', 'sym'])['Close'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().pct_change())
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example which gives input data and expected result.

Comment: @user19077881 More info: [mre] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). BTW, in a comment, you can just write `[mre]` and it turns into *[mre]*. More shorthands are listed here: [comment formatting](/editing-help#comment-formatting).